# How to find urdu text in urdu word vector in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an array of files in which all the files are stored now I have use a for loop to iterate over the files one by one and get the urdu text from the files
. while taking the urdu text I use to split() function to split the line and search each individual word in the urdu word vector .

**The problem is that it is not matching the urdu text in the word vector file**

```
 for pf in positiveFiles:
     with open(pf, "r",encoding="utf-8") as f:
        indexCounter = 0
        line=f.readline()
        split=line.split()
        for i in range(len(wordsList)): 
            if wordsList[i] == split:
                print(i)
            else:
                 print("no match")
```

It is showing the no match on all the words.

I want to get the index of each Urdu word . and all the Urdu words are located in `wordsList` with their indices

The urdu data inside the file is something like this

```
['\ufeffیار', 'یہ', 'اردو', 'رسم', 'الخط', 'میں', 'زیر،', 'زبر،', 'پیش', 'کیسے', 'لگاتے', 'ہیں؟کوئی', 'سمجھانے', 'تو']
3954
['\ufeff', 'سالہ', 'امل', 'کی', 'موت', '’کاش', 'کسی', 'بھی', 'والدین', 'کو', 'اتنی', 'بہادری', 'کا', 'مظاہرہ', 'نہ', 'کرنا', 'پڑے']
3954
['\ufeffہم', 'آ', 'جا', 'کر', 'تشخص', 'پاکستان،', 'اسلام', 'اور', 'اردو', 'زبان', 'کے', 'حوالے', 'سے', 'سلیبس', 'پر', 'فوکس', 'کرتے', 'ہیں۔']
```

I think the problem might be coming in single quotes

Comment: You’re comparing *each* element of `wordsList` against the *entire* list of `split` results.  (Your file also has a “UTF-8 BOM” that you should discard.)

Comment: can u please make an answer

Comment: I’m not confident that I understand *everything* that’s wrong well enough to write an answer.  Maybe you could post the whole example?

Comment: Does your urdu data file literally include the ``[``s and ``'``? Does ``wordsList `` contain the pasted urdu data? What is the purpose of ``indexCounter``?

Answer (score 0):

I did not get your question but you can simply go through some functions which you can use with list and I think you will not need to run a loop that you have written to compare element

ex. to find index of any element in list

```
listA = ['\ufeff', 'سالہ', 'امل', 'کی', 'موت', '’کاش', 'کسی', 'بھی', 'والدین', 'کو', 'اتنی', 'بہادری', 'کا', 'مظاہرہ', 'نہ', 'کرنا', 'پڑے']

'بھی' in listA
# this will return True if listA has that element
```

Second you can get index of element from list

```
listA = ['\ufeff', 'سالہ', 'امل', 'کی', 'موت', '’کاش', 'کسی', 'بھی', 'والدین', 'کو', 'اتنی', 'بہادری', 'کا', 'مظاہرہ', 'نہ', 'کرنا', 'پڑے']

try:               
    print(listA.index('کسی'))
except Exception as e: 
    print (e)
```

Comment: Pratik the problem is that wordsList is a numpy array and .index function is not working with that

Comment: when i am using .index it is showing me that
'Dictionary' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: You can try 
numpy.where( yourArray == element )
to get index of element